# Subset a dataset to only groups with 2 or more unique subgroups in R

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a dataset that I want to subset to only observations where a subgroup of a group have 2 or more unique classes, (I am trying to subset respondents in a survey who live in Nielsen DMA's that cross state lines.)

So if I have this dataframe:

```
start <- data.frame("obs"=seq(1,10, by=1),"grp"=c(rep("A",4), rep("B",3),rep("C",3)), "sub_grp"=c(rep("A1",2), rep("A2",2), rep("B1",3), "C1","C2","C3"))
```

What command would I need to subset it to this?

```
end <- data.frame("obs"=c(seq(1,4,by=1), seq(8,10, by=1)), "grp"=c(rep("A",4), rep("C",3)), "sub_grp"=c("A1","A1","A2","A2","C1","C2","C3"))
```

The datasets are all data.tables, so I figure there must be a special command in that package to do this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, you can check the number of unique values in *sub_grp* using `uniqueN`, if it's larger than one, keep the group with `.SD`:

```
setDT(start)[, if(uniqueN(sub_grp) > 1) .SD, grp]

#   grp obs sub_grp
#1:   A   1      A1
#2:   A   2      A1
#3:   A   3      A2
#4:   A   4      A2
#5:   C   8      C1
#6:   C   9      C2
#7:   C  10      C3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `dplyr` library:

```
library(dplyr)

start %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>%
  filter(length(unique(sub_grp)) >= 2) %>% 
  ungroup
```

This would give you the result:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
    obs   grp sub_grp
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
1     1     A      A1
2     2     A      A1
3     3     A      A2
4     4     A      A2
5     8     C      C1
6     9     C      C2
7    10     C      C3
```